# Querying for Ethereum nodes (like how ethernodes.org does it)

Tags: python, devp2p, ethernodes

I'm wondering how https://ethernodes.org/nodes works on the backend.

Did they just have a script using devp2p discovery.py (https://github.com/ethereum/pydevp2p/blob/develop/devp2p/discovery.py) or otherwise to pull this data?

For example, is there an example of getting such node stats such as total # nodes on the network, getting a list of them, getting client diversity info from them and so on?
Appreciate your insight Ethereum-ites!